# Duplicate Jar Entry error while generating release APK

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

Facing below error while generating release APK. This issue is coming after merging of an old branch.
I've checked similar posts and tried suggested solutions but didn't work.
Note: I'm able to build prod APK successfully.

> Warning: Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Can't
> write
> [C:\Users\shruti.tungar\AndroidStudioProjects\SodexoZeta\merchant-android-client\pos\build\intermediates\transforms\proguard\preKitkat\prod\0.jar]
> (Can't read
> [C:\Users\shruti.tungar\AndroidStudioProjects\SodexoZeta\merchant-android-client\pos\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\preKitkat\prod\26.jar(;;;;;;;**.class)]
> (Duplicate jar entry [in/zeta/android/o/j$a.class]))
>
> Task :pos:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForPreKitkatProd
> FAILED

Project's Build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.51'
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:${ANDROID_GRADLE_PLUGIN_VERSION}"

        // Simplify adding debug logs
        classpath 'com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-plugin:1.2.1'

        // Discover dependency updates
        classpath 'com.github.ben-manes:gradle-versions-plugin:0.13.0'

        classpath 'com.dicedmelon.gradle:jacoco-android:0.1.1'

        // Generate findbugs tasks for android projects
        classpath 'com.chaitanyapramod.gradle:findbugs-android:1.0'

        classpath 'com.github.JakeWharton.butterknife:butterknife-gradle-plugin:2a3ba161b39bcdad2e6d2a482eed67fd17c4440d'

        classpath('com.uber:okbuck:0.20.7') {
            // Prevents gradle resolving the version conflict by picking the higher version. OkBuck
            // depends on android gradle plugin 2.3
            exclude group: 'com.android.tools.build', module: 'gradle'
        }

        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:${GOOGLE_SERVICES_VERSION}"

        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.gradle.build-scan' version '1.11'
}

apply plugin: 'com.github.ben-manes.versions'
apply plugin: 'com.uber.okbuck'

buildScan {
    licenseAgreementUrl = 'https://gradle.com/terms-of-service'
    licenseAgree = 'yes'
}

okbuck {
    buildToolVersion = BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION
    target = "android-$COMPIlE_SDK_VERSION"

    extraBuckOpts = [
        'app'   : [
            'android_binary': ['trim_resource_ids = True']
        ],
        'bizapp': [
            'android_binary': ['trim_resource_ids = True']
        ]
    ]
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

ext.common_libs = [
    "com.google.code.gson:gson:${GSON_VERSION}",
    "com.google.guava:guava:${GUAVA_VERSION}",
    "com.google.dagger:dagger:$DAGGER_VERSION",
    'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9',
    "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:$TIMBER_VERSION",
    'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28',
    "com.android.support:support-v4:${ANDROID_SUPPORT_LIB_VERSION}",
    "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:${RXJAVA_VERSION}"
]

ext.common_test_libs = [
    'junit:junit:4.12',
    'org.assertj:assertj-core:1.7.1',
    'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.1.2',
    'org.robolectric:shadows-multidex:3.1.2'
]

ext.lint_options = {
    disable 'InvalidPackage' //butterKnife
    disable 'RequiredSize' // https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37138580
    warning 'GradleCompatible' //it's causing problems in integrating firebase perf.
    //I am keeping major version same for all all firebase and play services version so things should work fine. see D33744
    check 'Interoperability'
}

ext.compile_options = {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

ext.test_options = {
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
}

ext.android_settings_for_module = {
    compileSdkVersion COMPIlE_SDK_VERSION.toInteger()
    buildToolsVersion BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        }
    }
    compileOptions compile_options
    lintOptions lint_options
    testOptions test_options
}
```

pos module's build.gradle:

```
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        //TODO: extract dependencies common to app and bizapp into a single script.
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'
        classpath "com.getkeepsafe.dexcount:dexcount-gradle-plugin:$DEXCOUNT_VERSION"
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url 'https://zendesk.jfrog.io/zendesk/repo' }
    mavenCentral()
}

apply from: '../gitutils.gradle'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.hugo'
apply plugin: 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount'
apply from: '../zetautils.gradle'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'


dexcount {
    runOnEachAssemble false
}

boolean isDebuggable = project.hasProperty("debuggable").toBoolean()
boolean isWebDebuggable = project.hasProperty("webDebuggable").toBoolean() || isDebuggable
boolean enableCrashlytics = project.hasProperty("enableCrashlytics").toBoolean()
android {
    compileSdkVersion COMPIlE_SDK_VERSION.toInteger()
    buildToolsVersion BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "in.zeta.android.pos"
        buildConfigField "String", "APP_NAME", "\"ZetaPos\""
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 275
        // versionNameFormat: [Major].[Minor].[Patch]
        versionName "2.0.1"
        resConfigs 'en', 'xhdpi'
        setProperty("archivesBaseName", "zpos-v$versionName-" + getBranchName())
        multiDexEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt")

        testInstrumentationRunner "in.zeta.android.pos.MockTestRunner"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        prod {
            storeFile file(prod_keystore)
            storePassword prod_store_password
            keyAlias prod_key_alias
            keyPassword prod_key_password
        }
        preprod {
            storeFile file(preprod_keystore)
            storePassword preprod_store_password
            keyAlias preprod_key_alias
            keyPassword preprod_key_password
        }
        debug {
            storeFile file(debug_keystore)
            storePassword debug_store_password
            keyAlias debug_key_alias
            keyPassword debug_key_password
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "minsdk"
    productFlavors {
        preKitkat {
            dimension "minsdk"
        }
        postLollipop { // To be used for debug / dev only
            minSdkVersion 23 // Note: Not 21 as Lollipop supports only 100 dex files in an apk
            dimension "minsdk"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        //TODO: extract all these URL constants into a single file for both app and bizapp
        prod {
            matchingFallbacks = 'release'

            buildConfigField "String", "PROD_DOOR_ENDPOINT", "\"door-zcp-merchant.zeta.in:443\""
            buildConfigField "String", "DOOR_TLS_ENDPOINT", "\"door-zcp-merchant.zeta.in:443\""
            buildConfigField "String", "DOOR_RTLS_ENDPOINT", "\"door-rtls-merchant.zeta.in:443\""
            buildConfigField "boolean", "DOOR_PREFER_RTLS", "true"
            buildConfigField "boolean", "ENABLE_COMPRESSION", "true"
            buildConfigField "String", "DOOR_RTLS_TICKET_ENDPOINT", "\"https://api.gw.zetapay.in/zeta.in/ticket/1.0\""
            buildConfigField "String", "USER_SERVICE_ENDPOINT", "\"https://upload.gw.zetapay.in/\""
            buildConfigField "String", "TOKEN_SERVICE_ENDPOINT", "\"https://ts.gw.zetapay.in/ts/v1\""
            buildConfigField "String", "GCM_SENDER_ID", "\"559544507907\""
            buildConfigField "String", "MERCHANT_DIR_ENDPOINT", "\"https://merchantdir.zetaapps.in/index.html\""
            buildConfigField "String", "SUPER_TAG_ACTIVATOR_ENDPOINT", "\"super.zetaapps.in\""
            buildConfigField "String", "SUPER_TAG_MIME_TYPE", "\"application/vnd.in.zeta.pos\""
            buildConfigField "String", "MANAGE_MENU_ENDPOINT", "\"https://cafe-menu.zetaapps.in/?#menu\""

            buildConfigField "String", "ACCOUNT_TYPE", "\"in.zeta\""
            buildConfigField "String", "AUTHORITY", "\"in.zeta.android.pos.sync\""

            //Web debuggable prod app
            buildConfigField "boolean", "WEB_DEBUGGABLE", isWebDebuggable.toString()

            buildConfigField "boolean", "DOOR_MONITOR", project.hasProperty("monitorDoor").toString()

            buildConfigField "String", "ZETA_PUBLIC_KEY", "\"MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAlVBhgMhutjgfWFOiFRUXHXDGeUTGVSiLay52yIf4Gve+kTo96ISU+6XBuq8HMkQoleV0N0/8i2dATDZXxOVUKFKNE/lgwDkRqpItxzINpJs3lSQAdc4yO5krSAihFk3SkBuj1dU9e3/5JrwGmRWXkF0EgTiKwPQildn+8B5tjYkG/rbUzz+MsXkH+r41RDgdaq4nmuW/2zAFecNp4a+eS7cKjN0f0+JKQKbZtd1w1CL2DBsQJeo4T+zIFqWKZ5+ooWea9p9iTUtJsdPReUpJAqSJTifIgWAyWBCZIn0OVEYlOUeRMCi0gr/qN7EGb80DQSqfrilcQ5D6aQ4AGl6VkQIDAQAB\""
            buildConfigField "boolean", "FETCH_TEMPLATES_FROM_FILE", "false"

            buildConfigField "String", "ENVIRONMENT", "\"PROD\""
            buildConfigField "boolean", "ENABLE_CRASHLYTICS", "$enableCrashlytics"

            signingConfig signingConfigs.prod

            // shrink apk
            minifyEnabled !isDebuggable
            shrinkResources !isDebuggable

            debuggable isDebuggable
        }

        preprod {
            matchingFallbacks = 'release'

            buildConfigField "String", "PROD_DOOR_ENDPOINT", "\"door-zcp-merchant.zeta.in:443\""
            buildConfigField "String", "DOOR_TLS_ENDPOINT", "\"door-tls.mum1-pp.zetaapps.in:443\""
            buildConfigField "String", "DOOR_RTLS_ENDPOINT", "\"door-tcp.mum1-pp.zetaapps.in:5223\""
            buildConfigField "boolean", "DOOR_PREFER_RTLS", "false"
            buildConfigField "boolean", "ENABLE_COMPRESSION", "false"
            buildConfigField "String", "DOOR_RTLS_TICKET_ENDPOINT", "\"https://api.mum1-pp.zetaapps.in/zeta.in/ticket/1.0\""
            buildConfigField "String", "USER_SERVICE_ENDPOINT", "\"https://upload.pmum1-pp.zetaapps.in/\""
            buildConfigField "String", "TOKEN_SERVICE_ENDPOINT", "\"https://tsmum1-pp.zetaapps.in/ts/v1\""
            buildConfigField "String", "GCM_SENDER_ID", "\"559544507907\""
            buildConfigField "String", "MERCHANT_DIR_ENDPOINT", "\"https://merchantdir-mum1-pp.zetaapps.in/index.html\""
            buildConfigField "String", "SUPER_TAG_ACTIVATOR_ENDPOINT", "\"super-preprod.zetaapps.in\""
            buildConfigField "String", "SUPER_TAG_MIME_TYPE", "\"application/vnd.in.zeta.pos.preprod\""
            buildConfigField "String", "MANAGE_MENU_ENDPOINT", "\"https://cafe-menu-preprod.zetaapps.in/?#menu\""
            buildConfigField "String", "QUICKSHOP_ENDPOINT", "\"https://api.mum1-pp.zetaapps.in/\""
            buildConfigField "String", "ACCOUNT_TYPE", "\"in.zeta.preprod\""
            buildConfigField "String", "AUTHORITY", "\"in.zeta.android.pos.preprod.sync\""

            //Web debuggable prod app
            buildConfigField "boolean", "WEB_DEBUGGABLE", isWebDebuggable.toString()

            buildConfigField "boolean", "DOOR_MONITOR", project.hasProperty("monitorDoor").toString()

            buildConfigField "String", "ZETA_PUBLIC_KEY", "\"MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAlVBhgMhutjgfWFOiFRUXHXDGeUTGVSiLay52yIf4Gve+kTo96ISU+6XBuq8HMkQoleV0N0/8i2dATDZXxOVUKFKNE/lgwDkRqpItxzINpJs3lSQAdc4yO5krSAihFk3SkBuj1dU9e3/5JrwGmRWXkF0EgTiKwPQildn+8B5tjYkG/rbUzz+MsXkH+r41RDgdaq4nmuW/2zAFecNp4a+eS7cKjN0f0+JKQKbZtd1w1CL2DBsQJeo4T+zIFqWKZ5+ooWea9p9iTUtJsdPReUpJAqSJTifIgWAyWBCZIn0OVEYlOUeRMCi0gr/qN7EGb80DQSqfrilcQ5D6aQ4AGl6VkQIDAQAB\""
            buildConfigField "boolean", "FETCH_TEMPLATES_FROM_FILE", "false"

            buildConfigField "String", "ENVIRONMENT", "\"PREPROD\""
            buildConfigField "boolean", "ENABLE_CRASHLYTICS", "$enableCrashlytics"

            applicationIdSuffix ".preprod"

            signingConfig signingConfigs.preprod

            minifyEnabled !isDebuggable
            shrinkResources !isDebuggable

            ext.enableCrashlytics = enableCrashlytics

            debuggable isDebuggable
        }

        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"

            buildConfigField "String", "PROD_DOOR_ENDPOINT", "\"door-zcp.zeta.in:443\""
            buildConfigField "String", "DOOR_TLS_ENDPOINT", "\"door-tcp.stage.zeta.in:2718\""
            buildConfigField "String", "DOOR_RTLS_ENDPOINT", "\"door-tcp.stage.zeta.in:5223\""
            buildConfigField "boolean", "DOOR_PREFER_RTLS", "true"
            buildConfigField "boolean", "ENABLE_COMPRESSION", "true"
            buildConfigField "String", "DOOR_RTLS_TICKET_ENDPOINT", "\"https://api.stage.zeta.in/zeta.in/ticket/1.0\""
            buildConfigField "String", "USER_SERVICE_ENDPOINT", "\"https://upload.stage.zeta.in/\""
            buildConfigField "String", "USER_FEEDS_ENDPOINT", "\"http://ec2-54-255-188-206.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com:2334?\""
            buildConfigField "String", "SHADOW_CARD_ENDPOINT", "\"https://shadowcard.stage.zeta.in:5000/sc/v1\""
            buildConfigField "String", "TOKEN_SERVICE_ENDPOINT", "\"https://shadowcard.stage.zeta.in:8005/ts/v1\""
            buildConfigField "String", "SUPER_CARD_ENDPOINT", "\"https://acs.stage.zeta.in/supercard\""
            buildConfigField "String", "GCM_SENDER_ID", "\"559544507907\""
            buildConfigField "String", "MERCHANT_DIR_ENDPOINT", "\"https://merchantdir.zetaapps.in/index.html\""
            buildConfigField "String", "SUPER_TAG_ACTIVATOR_ENDPOINT", "\"super-stage.zetaapps.in\""
            buildConfigField "String", "SUPER_TAG_MIME_TYPE", "\"application/vnd.in.zeta.pos.debug\""
            buildConfigField "String", "MANAGE_MENU_ENDPOINT", "\"https://cafe-menu-stage.zetaapps.in/?#menu\""

            buildConfigField "boolean", "DOOR_MONITOR", "true"

            buildConfigField "String", "ACCOUNT_TYPE", "\"in.zeta.debug\""
            buildConfigField "String", "AUTHORITY", "\"in.zeta.android.pos.debug.sync\""

            buildConfigField "boolean", "WEB_DEBUGGABLE", "true"

            buildConfigField "String", "ZETA_PUBLIC_KEY", "\"MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAlVBhgMhutjgfWFOiFRUXHXDGeUTGVSiLay52yIf4Gve+kTo96ISU+6XBuq8HMkQoleV0N0/8i2dATDZXxOVUKFKNE/lgwDkRqpItxzINpJs3lSQAdc4yO5krSAihFk3SkBuj1dU9e3/5JrwGmRWXkF0EgTiKwPQildn+8B5tjYkG/rbUzz+MsXkH+r41RDgdaq4nmuW/2zAFecNp4a+eS7cKjN0f0+JKQKbZtd1w1CL2DBsQJeo4T+zIFqWKZ5+ooWea9p9iTUtJsdPReUpJAqSJTifIgWAyWBCZIn0OVEYlOUeRMCi0gr/qN7EGb80DQSqfrilcQ5D6aQ4AGl6VkQIDAQAB\""
            buildConfigField "boolean", "FETCH_TEMPLATES_FROM_FILE", "false"

            buildConfigField "String", "ENVIRONMENT", "\"STAGING\""
            buildConfigField "boolean", "ENABLE_CRASHLYTICS", "$enableCrashlytics"

            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            debuggable true
            ext.betaDistributionGroupAliases = "zpos-testers"
            // Disable fabric build ID generation for debug builds
            ext.enableCrashlytics = enableCrashlytics
            ext.alwaysUpdateBuildId = false
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude '.readme'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }

    // Prevent unnecessary configurations from being part of build and tests
    variantFilter { variant ->
        def flavor = variant.getFlavors().get(0)
        def buildType = variant.buildType

        if (flavor.name == 'postLollipop' && buildType.name != 'debug') {
            variant.setIgnore true
        }

        if (buildType.name == 'release') {
            variant.setIgnore true
        }

        if (project.hasProperty('disablePostLollipop') && flavor.name == 'postLollipop') {
            variant.setIgnore true
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    lintOptions { // Temp workaround as lint.xml is not read in Android Gradle plugin 2.3.x
        warning 'InvalidPackage'
        warning 'GradleCompatible' //it's causing problems in integrating firebase perf.
        // I am keeping major version same for all all firebase and play services version so things should work fine. see D33744
        warning 'ExpiredTargetSdkVersion'
    }
}

dependencies {
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$DAGGER_VERSION"
    kapt "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:$BUTTERKNIFE_VERSION"
    implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:$CONSTRAINT_LAYOUT_VERSION"
    implementation 'com.scottyab:rootbeer-lib:0.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.zopim.android:sdk:1.4.1'
    implementation project(":bizapp")
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```